# Typo3 can't save record

Tags: typo3, forum

I am trying to install the typo3_forum extension as shown [here](https://github.com/mittwald/typo3-forum/blob/master/Documentation/Configuration/Installation/Index.rst).

But when I try to save the record of a new forum, the title field gets highlighted in red and the form is rejected.

[image: Whatever I enter gets deleted]

What could be the cause of this error? Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't on topic here, SO is for programming questions. You're probably better off using Typo3's (or the plugin's) own support resources for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's obvious, when you are trying to save you should have an alert, haven't you?

> The fields marked with an exclamation mark are not yet correctly filled in. Please complete them properly.

That means that this field is just required.

Comment: Go to install tool and use 'Compare current database with specification' to make sure that all required DB fields are created properly

Comment: After doing that, i got an error saying `Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'storage_pid' at row 1` which, after a quick google search lead me to turn off strict mode in mysql. Now everything works like a charm! Thanks, biesior.